# selenium with threading, crashing and memory to be 99%

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, scrape

I want to check which webpage exists on Twitter; the amount of 3000 Twitter URLs needs to be checked. The below code is working as expected without threading. To save time, I added the multi_threads. However, it constantly crashes. I have checked the task management; the memory is 100%. Can any help me? Appreciate any help in advance.

```py
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import threading
from threading import Thread
import xlsxwriter

#check
def check_link(ceo_url):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path,options=options)
    driver.get(ceo_url)

    try: 
        `find element which not exsit in the empty`
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'.//div[@data-testid="primaryColumn"]//section[@aria-labelledby="accessible-list-0"]')))

        `if above element, then write in the excel column 1`
        worksheet.write(i+1,0,driver.current_url)
        i += 1
    except TimeoutException:
        'if not write in the column 2'
        worksheet.write(j+1,1,driver.current_url)
        j += 1

    
    driver.quit()




def open_file():    
    my_file = open('information.txt','r')
    names = my_file.read().lower()
    data_into_list = names.replace(' ','').split('\n')
    my_file.close()
    return data_into_list

def print_urls(data_into_list):
    CEO_names = data_into_list
    ceo_urls = []
    for CEO_name in CEO_names:
        url = 'https://twitter.com/{}'.format(CEO_name)
        ceo_urls.append(url)
    return ceo_urls



def main():
    i = 0
    j = 0
    threads = []
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Twitter.xlsx')
    worksheet  = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')

    `read name from txt files`
    data_into_list = open_file()
    ceo_urls = print_urls(data_into_list)

    `add thread`
    for i, ceo_url in enumerate(ceo_urls):
        threads.append(Thread(target=check_link,args=(ceo_url)))
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
   

if __name__ = '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Good God, man!  You're starting 3,000 threads all at once, EACH of which starts a new Chrome browser instance, and you're surprised there are resource problems?  You desperately need the `multiprocessing` module, where you can create a pool of threads that handle the tasks in reasonably-sized chunks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me how to choose the reasinably-sized? If i use the single thread, i will need more than 4 hours. Can u guess how long do i need to spend if i use mutiprocessing?

Comment: With I/O-bound workloads, it's a little hard to tell.  Probably 2x the number of processors you have would be reasonable.  Maybe  a bit more.  However, there's another issue.  There's no guarantee that `xlsxwriter` is thread-safe.  You're going to be writing cells from multiple threads at once.  That might not work.  You'll have to see what happens.  You may need to use a `multiprocessing.Lock` to protect that sequence.